# Tutors for Sorceries?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm building a budget [Natural Order](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Natural%20Order) deck, so I'm looking for tutors that can find sorcerys in green and black, preferably that have CMC 3 or less. I hope you can help.

Comment: Natural Order is budget?

Comment: "Budget" natural order use some tutors and 2 Natural Orders to reduce the cost by a bit. Less Natural Orders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following cards in black and green will allow you to search your library for a sorcery, and possibly other cards:

- [Bringer of the Black Dawn](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bringer%20of%20the%20Black%20Dawn)
- **[Cruel Tutor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cruel%20Tutor)**
- [Demonic Collusion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Demonic%20Collusion)
- **[Demonic Tutor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Demonic%20Tutor)**
- **[Diabolic Intent](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Diabolic%20Intent)**
- [Diabolic Revelation](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Diabolic%20Revelation)
- [Diabolic Tutor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Diabolic%20Tutor)
- **[Entomb](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Entomb)** (tutors to the graveyard)
- **[Grim Tutor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Grim%20Tutor)**
- **[Imperial Seal](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Imperial%20Seal)** (tutors to the top of the library)
- [Increasing Ambition](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Increasing%20Ambition)
- **[Infernal Tutor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Infernal%20Tutor)**
- [Insidious Dreams](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Insidious%20Dreams)
- [Liliana Vess](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Liliana%20Vess) (tutors to the top of the library)
- **[Rhystic Tutor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rhystic%20Tutor)**
- [Rune-Scarred Demon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rune-Scarred%20Demon)
- [Sidisi, Undead Vizier](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sidisi%2C%20Undead%20Vizier)
- **[Vampiric Tutor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Vampiric%20Tutor)** (tutors to the top of the library)

I've highlighted the cards with converted mana cost 3 or less.

There are also black cards with Transmute, which allows you to pay {1}{B}{B} and discard that card to search for a card with the same CMC:

- [Brainspoil](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Brainspoil)
- [Dimir House Guard](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dimir%20House%20Guard)
- [Dimir Machinations](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dimir%20Machinations)
- [Netherborn Phalanx](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Netherborn%20Phalanx)
- [Shred Memory](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shred%20Memory)

In addition, [Demonic Consultation](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Demonic%20Consultation) isn't exactly a tutor, but it does let you get a specific card out of your library into your hand, at the cost of exiling every card above it, and with a chance of exiling your whole library without finding it. [Spoils of the Vault](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Spoils%20of%20the%20Vault) has a similar effect, except that you're guaranteed to find the card if it's in there, but you lose 1 life for each card exiled.

Comment: Spoils of the Vault, "only" one mana!

Comment: @Jefromi But if you are really unlucky you can kill yourself with it, or if you misname a card :p

Comment: +1 from me. You might mention that you used the advanced search features of the Gatherer to compile this list (teach the OP to fish).

Comment: @Rainbolt I considered it, but most of it was just looking at every card in the given colors with "search your library" in the text. I didn't know until after I compiled the list that every card would be of the "search your library for a card" variety.

Comment: Just for completeness' sake: There are a few more cards such as Beseech the Queen (just BBB!), Phyrexian Portal, Ring of Three Wishes and Maralen of the Mornsong that also work, although they are more situational and/or just plan worse.

Comment: For reference, I missed Beseech the Queen because I omitted the word "land" to avoid looking through the 500 or so green land tutors, I missed Phyrexian Portal and Ring of Three wishes because I didn't think to search artifacts, and I missed Maralen because it's worded oddly ("searches" instead of "search").